# multiple if in if with get url

Tags: if-statement, geturl

i want to select from database by url and for this i do this if:

```
if (isset($_GET['class']) == 'dw')
{
    $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [dw] > 0 order by credits asc");
}
if (isset($_GET['class']) == 'bk')
{
    $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [bk] > 0 order by credits asc");
}
if (isset($_GET['class']) == 'fe')
{
    $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [fe] > 0 order by credits asc");
}
if (isset($_GET['class']) == 'mf')
{
    $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [mf] > 0 order by credits asc");
}
if (isset($_GET['class']) == 'dl')
{
    $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [dl] > 0 order by credits asc");
}
if (isset($_GET['class']) == 'sum')
{
    $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [sum] > 0 order by credits asc");
}
if (isset($_GET['class']) == 'rf')
{
    $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [rf] > 0 order by credits asc");
}
else
{
    $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' order by credits asc");
}
```

Url for this is: `index.php?sy=items&class=dw`

but when i access this url `index.php?sy=items&class=dw` is selected last if :( : `index.php?sy=items&class=rf`

can help me to resolve for work with each if ?

Comment: The last else will always be evaluated. You should probably try a case statement, elseif or nested if structures.

Answer (score 0):

Here Try to change the format of your code in this pattern...

```
$class=$_GET['class']
switch($class) {
    case 'dw':
        $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [dw] > 0 order by credits asc");
        break;
    case 'bk':
        $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [bk] > 0 order by credits asc");
        break;
    case 'fe':
         $query  = mssql_query("select * from [WebShop] where [category]='".secure($string)."' and [fe] > 0 order by credits asc");
        break;
    default:
    code to be executed if n is different from all labels;
}
```